# How to get the selected rows from different pages in a data table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using these script to get the rows from the data table,but it's giving the current page selected row values only.How can we get all the rows from all the pages which are present in the data table using jQuery.

Code:

```
var tablevalues =[];

    $("#table-sparkline").dataTable().fnDestroy();  
    var oTable2 = $('#table-sparkline').dataTable({
                "aaSorting": []
    });
    oTable2.fnClearTable();

               //alert("in nth child");
               //var values = $(this).html();        
               //alert(values);
        var table = $('#example1').DataTable(); 
        tablevalues.length=0;
        tablevalues=(table.rows('.selected').data());
        for(var i=0;i<tablevalues.length;i++){

        oTable2.fnAddData([
                tablevalues[i]
                ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put the table into one page, use "datatables".

Comment: WHat do you actualy want to achieve? Like getting SUM of column 1 of all the rows,etc?

Comment: I want all the selected rows in all pages,there is no sum ,just I want to display the select rows to the user @Saswat

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve all data, you need to make a separate AJAX request mimicking the behavior of the DataTables.

You can use `ajax.params()`, that gets the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.

```
function processAllRecords(){
   var req = $('#example1 table').DataTable().ajax.params();

   // Reset request parameters to retrieve all records
   req.start = 0;
   req.length = -1;
   req.search.value = "";

   // Request data
   $.ajax({
      'url': 'script.php',
      'data': req,
      'dataType': 'json'
   })
   .done(function(json){
      // json.data is array of data source objects (array/object),
      // one for each row
      console.log(json);
   });
}
```